# How can I restart a command within the same command in discord.py? Not asking for restarting the bot

Tags: discord.py

```py
@commands.command(name= 'p_start')
async def timer(self,ctx):
await ctx.send("Restart the pomodoro?")
    msg = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m:m.author==ctx.author and m.channel.id==ctx.channel.id)
    if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):
        cmd = self.client.get_invoke('p_start')
        await cmd(ctx)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bye!")
```

Hello, I am trying to add a piece of code that restarts the p_start command after getting yes or y answer from the author/user. I am not getting any error, however even though I type yes/y I get the text "bye" from the bot. How can I restart a command within the same command?

Answer (score 0):

You said `if msg.content.lower in ("y", "yes"):`, which is checking the *method* `lower` of the string. You'll actually get something like `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fb66b032470>` which is not really what you want.

Also, you should be `invoke`-ing the command directly with the callback, rather than getting it through `get_invoke` which I'm not sure what that is for as it doesn't exist in the documentation.

```py
        if msg.content.lower() in ("y", "yes"):
            cmd = await self.timer.invoke(ctx)
```

Comment: Hello, when I changed the code in the way you recommended I am receiving this error                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sinembilgeguler/Desktop/Python/music.py", line 138, in timer
    await cmd(ctx)
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Comment: The command was actually already invoked. You can actually just delete that because there isn’t any point in returning something out of the command